# How to prevent some values in R.java from changing when adding/updating resources

Tags: android, android-resources, r.java-file

I need to store the link to the image, which user has chosen. The sources of the images are files, contact icons and resources' drawables (I need drawables since I provide different images for different resolutions/densities).
For the purpose of unification I store it in URI, and consequently this URI may be pointing to a **file** (`file://`), to **content provider** or to **resource** (`android.resource://...`). Here is how the URI pointing to drawable with id=2130837534 looks like:

```
android.resource://my.packagename/2130837534
```

It works fine unless the ids in `R.java` are regenerated. So, is there any way to prevent SDK from changing some of the `R.java` ids values?

Comment: You should be storing the *name* of the resource. For example, `icon.png` won't change but it's resource id very well might. You can always use `Resources.getIdentifier(String name, String defType, String defPackage)` to get the actual resource id from the resource name.

Comment: You could rely on a hack, the resource id's are generated in alphabetical order within their category so use that. Such a horrible answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't, and shouldn't. If you can describe your problem clearly, there might be some other solution.

Save your resource names in a file, in this way.

icon_profile_1
icon_profile_2

And then when you need the resource ID, do this.

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("icon_profile_1", "drawable","your_package_name");
```

[Check here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier)(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: Isn't it clear? Ok, I'll add an Uri example. BTW, why "shouldn't"?

Comment: I mean't your use-case. Why can't you keep resource IDs instead of Uris

Comment: Since I refer to IDs outside the code (for example, storing them in a file), it would be the same whether to keep just an ID or an ID + preceding _android.resource://my.packagename/_ string

Comment: Ok, You can store the resource names, and then convert them back to IDs at runtime. Would that help?

Comment: H'm, that looks reasonable. Could you, please, update your answer with this suggestion to make it clearer for others why I accept it.

Answer (score 1):

As R.java is auto-generated it can't be restricted from it's operation, because it will agin be auto-generated when your project is cleaned or compiled.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible In android because R.java is Autogenrated and you cant do anything for that.